# Showing required roles in a Symfony 2.1 403 forbidden page

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a Symfony 2.1 application that has various access controlled areas. My set up includes an administrative area for users to manage their accounts, another area for company admin users to manage their company accounts and backends for us and the office staff.

All these different users have defined roles, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN etc. The firewalls set up in my security.yml work fine for handling these different cases, however when a user accesses a page without the required role then get a generic 403 forbidden page.

I would like to have a custom page that has different content depending on the required role that the user is missing. I.e., you can't access this page because you're not an admin|company admin.

I need to retrieve the required roles of the route that has lead to the exception, I can then compare that against the user. Is there a good way to do this?

Many thanks in advance,
Al

Comment: take a look [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html)

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: @samra No, unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom access denied url and implement your own controller.

A good example is posted here: http://michelsalib.com/2011/03/31/advance-customization-of-the-403-error-page-in-symfony2/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not keen on this solution as it requires an extra bundle and using annotations for security. I might end up doing this but I'd like a "purer" solution if there is one.

Comment: I had a go at switching to this, but unfortunately this code doesn't seem to work with Symfony 2.1.